# Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the topology of $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ for which $U = \emptyset$ or $U^c$ is countable. Determine is this space is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the topology of $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ for which $U = \emptyset$ or $U^c$ is countable. Determine is this space is Hausdorff?

So $\mathscr{T}$ is the cocountable topology on $\Bbb R$. In order for the space $(\Bbb R, \mathscr{T})$ to be Hausdorff I need that for $x,y \in \Bbb R$ and $O_x, O_y \in \mathscr{T}$ the intersection $O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset.$

Now this intersection is empty if $(O_x \cap O_y)^c = O_x^c \cup O_y^c$ is not countable. So I have $$(O_x \cap O_y)^c = O_x^c \cup O_y^c=(\Bbb R \setminus O_x) \cup (\Bbb R \setminus O_y) $$ but I don't have information about $O_x$ and $O_y$ other than that since they contain $x$ and $y$ respectively they're non-empty and thus the complement of both is countable? So why wouldn't $O_x^c \cup O_y^c$ be countable as the union of two countable sets?

Comment: The intersection is empty if $O_x^c \cup O_y^c$ is the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

$x\neq y \in \Bbb{R}$ .

Suppose there exists $x\in  O_x, y\in O_y \in \mathscr{T}$  and $O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset.$

Hence, $(O_x )^c, (O_y )^c$ are countable.

Then, $(O_x \cap O_y)^c = O_x^c \cup O_y^c =\Bbb{R}$

$(O_x )^c\cup ( O_y)^c =\Bbb{R}$

$\implies  \Bbb{R}$ is countable, which is a contradiction.

Hence, the existence of two non empty disjoint set $O_x,  O_y $ containing two disjoint points $x, y $ , is not possible.

Hence, $ (\Bbb R, \mathscr{T})$ is not Hausdorff space.

Comment: How is $O_x^c \cup O_y^c = \Bbb R$?

Comment: $(O_x \cap O_y )^c= (\emptyset)^c$

Comment: $O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset$ was what we are trying to prove, not something we assumed?

Comment: I think you're striving for a contradiction here? Assuming that $O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset$ and then getting a contradiction by $\Bbb R$ being countable. I think you should clarify that in the answer.

Comment: Ok. I will put more information.

Comment: You can state it more positively: if $U,V$ are non-empty open sets of the cocountle topology, they intersect (i.e. their intersection cannot be empty). This not only shows the space is not Hausdorff but also that it's connected. In fact countable intersections of non-empty open sets have non-empty intersection too (and are even open). So this space is also Baire.